# How can I skip the first argument in an ash/dash shell function?

Tags: shell, ash, dash-shell

In an ash/dash function, I can refer to the full parameter list like this:

```
allparameters() { echo "$@"; }
```

Which gives me:

```
$ allparameters yyyyy abffcd efgh
yyyyy abffcd efgh
```

I want to skip `yyyyy`, so I tried [`${@:2}`](/a/9057392/8492116):

```
butlast() { echo "${@:2}"; }
```

However, this skips the first two characters:

```
$ butlast yyyyy abffcd efgh
yyy abffcd efgh
$ butlast abffcd efgh
ffcd efgh
```

I wasn’t able to find the colon syntax in [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ash) for ash, so that may be a bash-ism. What is the equivalent?

Comment: It looks like `ash` is applying `:` to a single string formed from the positional arguments, rather than the "array" of arguments. Not sure if that's a bug or expected (but undocumented) behavior. In `dash` it's just a "bad substitution" error.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`${name:offset}` is a `bash`ism, but you can use the POSIX `shift` command for what you want.

```
$ butlast() { shift; echo "$@"; }
$ butlast foo bar baz
bar baz
```